# How to lubricate my double kickstand? (ursus jumbo)

Tags: maintenance

It used to move real smooth but not anymore. There's this plastic cover that says 'remove to lubricate', but underneath it I don't find access to the hinge mechanism. I'm thinking of just putting some general purpose grease in the hinge, see second picture.

Couldn't find info on this on the Ursus website, also their support didn't answer me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just blob some grease on it.

Comment: OK I blobbed it with standard lithium grease on both sides, works really well now! I even made a dust cover out of duct tape, to keep debris out of the grease, but it looked ugly so I removed it again.

Comment: Side note: lithium grease is an overkill: it is good for its anti-corrosion property and for its higher melting temperature (and better low-temperature performance).

I guess the stand is aluminium made, and that you do not ride into furnaces or similars.

Enjoy the ride :) !

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have a bigger problem. Look at the blue and red circles:
[image: your stand]
Is something missing? Looking at the original picture from interneat searches it looks so. What is the material of that part? plastic or aluminium/steel? and why it is red itself?

I have the feeling that it does not move smooth because it is not anymore solidly attached to the frame, but it has some play/slack and therefore not opening/closing smoothly.

Check the frame for scratches&co where the red circle should attach. If I am correct, you will find some, in the long term this stand may ruin your frame (---> do not grease it, toss it away or use for some beater).

I hope I am wrong.

Comment: It looks a bit worse for wear, though.

Comment: You're right it should be symmetrical, it's messing a flimsy aluminum protrusion that's supposed to sort of grab onto the frame. It's reddish because I just painted my bike. I mounted everything back a few days ago (after lubricating the hinges from underneath) and it's perfectly stable and solid.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning and lubing mine today, I found that you can squirt grease in the little hole on the right between the two plate holding screw holes, and grease will squirt out on top of the legs.  Grease will also squirt out the lower plate holding hole, so put the screw back in 1st.

Grime had built up on top of one leg in it's pivot socket and kept the legs from folding up all the way.